.NET MAUI Hybrid Blazor with Bootstrap - Accordian doesn't work
I'm using .NET MAUI Hybrid and using the Bootstrap that came with the setup (version 5.1) but I also noticed that there is no javascript element that is associated with it.  I'm using the CSS classes for laying out the screen, but now I'd like to implement an Accordian and it seems without the javascript, it won't expand or collapse.
Is there anyway to use Bootstrap components with the installed version of Bootstrap under .NET MAUI Hybrid?

Have you even checked to see if the script has been added to use js for bootstrap elements? <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

I checked, but wasn't sure of what the source for the script would be.  I wonder why that would not be part of the template?  It is working now...thanks.
